# How to not hover on visibility hidden elements?

Tags: html, css, hover, visibility

In the following two snippets of HTML code, I want the outer DIV to look the same width as the most widest element, and whenever I hover on `.title`, the '.menu' shows.

```
<div>
      <span class="title">abcdefghijklmn</span>
      <span class="menu">
           <span class="child">abcde</span>
           <span class="child">abcd</span>
           <span class="child">abc</span>
           <span class="child">ab</span>
      </span>
</div>
```

Notice the words in `.title` is longer than those in `.child`

```
<div>
      <span class="title">abcde</span>
      <span class="menu">
           <span class="child">abcdefghijklmn</span>
           <span class="child">abcd</span>
           <span class="child">abc</span>
           <span class="child">ab</span>
      </span>
</div>
```

I tried to use the following CSS to get around to it, but `hover` didn't work out well.

```
.container {
  color:#fff;
  display: inline-block;
}
.title {
  background: blue;
}
.title, .menu {
    display: list-item;
}

.menu {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.child {
    display: block;
    background: red;
}

.title:hover + span{
    visibility: visible;
}
.menu:hover {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

see [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/zolopa/1/edit) here

**Notice** here, I didn't use `display` to toggle the `.menu`, because when `hover` on `div` you get to see `.title` get expanded quite obnoxiously. So I turned to using `visibility`, but another issue popped up, is that I can `hover` on `div` even I am not on '.title`, is there a workaround to this whole thing? or hovering on visibility hidden elements can be avoided?

Comment: _“is that I can hover on `div` even I am not on `.title`”_ – well of course, because the non-visibility of a descendant element doesn’t change the fact that the `div` itself occupies the whole area. Go read up on the _adjacent sibling combinator_, that’ll help solve this “problem”.

Comment: @CBroe adjacent sibling works, but I will not use `visibility` cuz it doesn't work well when I want to capture click under the non-visibility area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that your DOM structure influence the CSS selector. So far as your DOM and the issue, must use **Adjacent sibling selectors**.

## [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/haboqokarida/2/edit)

Change

```
div:hover .menu {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

To

```
.title:hover + span{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

[Here is a link.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#child-selectors)

Comment: Exactly what is said in the comments. But non-visibility elements pose another serious problem is that they are still take up that area so any mouse events will be captured by them.

Comment: @Lucaz Look this. **pointer-events** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: interesting one I'll look into it, but due to poor compatibility not practical in my project. :)

Answer (score 1):

Update your CSS with following

```
     .title, .menu {
        display: list-item;
    }

    .menu {
        visibility: hidden;

    }
    div
    {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    div:hover .menu {
        visibility: visible;
    }
```

You will get result.

Comment: not working...I think `inline-block` can also be expanded to the total height of its children.